# Class ThreadSafeStore Why to be checked the fields " _store" is equal to null

Tags: json.net

In the file:
https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs#L70

Why to be checked the fields " _store" is equal to null

Comment: The check for null is because the dictionary might not have been initialized yet. More importantly, why do you want to know? Are you experiencing trouble with this specific line or block of code?

Comment: The field cannot be null。

Comment: That is true, the field is always initialized in the constructor. Looking at the history of the file, it looks like the field was not always initialized in the constructor, so the null-check was previously required. I haven't tested it, but the null-check can probably be removed now. But again, why do you want to know - Is this piece of code causing errors or performance issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null-check is present, because the dictionary called `_store` might not have been initialized yet. In the constructor of the class, `_store` ***is initialized***, which would make the null-check irrelevant, as it would always be initialized.

By [looking at the history of the file](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commits/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs), it seems that `_store` was not always initialized in the constructor (this was added some time in 2012). In this case, the null-check would be required, as an exception would occur if you tried to add an entry to a dictionary that wasn't initialized.

This gives a hint that the null-check is most likely an artifact from when it wasn't initialized in the constructor. Without looking at the entire project, my guess is that the null-check can probably be removed, without causing any problems.